# How to make apropos read MANPATH

Tags: man, apropos

I am an unprivileged user on a system, so I have installed some software in my home directory. In addition to adding `~/.local/usr/bin` to my `PATH`, I've added `~/.local/usr/share/man` to my `MANPATH` so I can query the man pages for those packages.

For example, one such command is `cgdb`.

`man cgdb` works fine, it is getting the manpage from my `MANPATH` environment variable.

But `apropos cgdb` (`man -k cgdb`, `whatis cgdb`) is not working.

```
$ apropos cgdb
cgdb: nothing appropriate
```

I read in `man apropos` then `man whatis` that the whatis database can be regenerated with `makewhatis`, but it seems this can only be done by a privileged user in the system directories. I couldn't find any way to do this in user space.

Is it possible to use `apropos` (a.k.a. `man -k`) on non-system directories pointed to by `MANPATH` by non-privileged users?

FWIW: this is on a CentOS 6 server

```
$ uname -osrv
Linux 2.6.32-754.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 26 15:38:56 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Answer (score 1):

`apropos` typically reads a pre-generated index file for speed, rather than searching every manpage.

This means the index file needs to be updated whenever manpages are added.

On CentOS 6 the system manpages are updated nightly via the cron job in `/etc/cron.daily/makewhatis.cron`.

Now `makewhatis` is *meant* to be able to take the `-o` flag to let you specify your own directory.  However it doesn't seem to work...

```
% makewhatis -v $HOME/man -o $HOME/man/whatis
about to enter /home/sweh/man
skipping /var/cache/man - whatis file is readonly
% cat man/whatis
%
```

However `makewhatis` is a script, so it's possible to copy it and modify it to specify a new path:

```
% diff mymakewhatis /usr/sbin/makewhatis 
69c69
< DEFWHATISDIR=$HOME/man
---
> DEFWHATISDIR=/var/cache/man
```

Now:

```
% ./mymakewhatis -v $HOME/man 
about to enter /home/sweh/man
adding /home/sweh/man/man1/smbsh.1
```

And we can see it now has an entry:

```
% cat man/whatis 
smbsh                (1)  - Allows access to remote SMB shares using UNIX commands
```

And `apropos` works:

```
% man -k smbsh
smbsh                (1)  - Allows access to remote SMB shares using UNIX commands
```